# Как сгруппировать общие элементы окна в единый шаблон? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, шаблоны

Хочу собрать общие характеристики всех окон в один шаблон(?), а конкретно: верхний туллбар  окна (код xaml и методы-обработчики кнопок c#) и элемент border, находящийся внутри окна и выступающий в роли главного контейнера для всего контента. Есть ли в принципе такая возможность?

Туллбар:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
                    Background="#FF151192"
                    MouseDown="WindowPanel_MouseDown">
            <Button Width="20" Content="⨉" FontSize="13" 
                    x:Name="WindowCloseButton"
                    Foreground="White" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Click="WindowCloseButton_Click"/>
            <Button Width="20" Content="" FontSize="13" 
                    Foreground="White" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    x:Name="WindowHideButton"
                    Click="WindowHideButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Обработчики:

```
private void WindowPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            DragMove();
    }
    private void WindowCloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    private void WindowHideButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

Border:

```
<Border Background="#181735">
  Контент окна
</Border>
```

Comment: `UserControl` вас спасет.

Comment: @aepot, не подскажете, где найти конкретную технологию? Попытался сегодня сделать UserControl в виде контейнера <Border> с несколькими контейнерами внутри. При попытке использовать UC в нужном окне он ничего не делал и уж тем более не выступал в роли контейнера